# PHP DOM odd output?

Tags: php, domdocument

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<columns>
    <column>
        <originalName>ORP</originalName>
        <name>ORP</name>
        <visible>1</visible>
    </column>
    <column>
        <originalName>OKRES</originalName>
        <name>OKRES</name>
        <visible>1</visible>
    </column>
    <column>
        <originalName>Objekt</originalName>
        <name>Objekt</name>
        <visible>1</visible>
    </column>
    <column>
        <originalName>Školenie</originalName>
        <name>Skolenie</name>
        <visible>1</visible>
    </column>
    <column>
        <originalName>Dátum posledného školenia OPP</originalName>
        <name>DatumPoslednehoSkoleniaOPP</name>
        <visible>1</visible>
    </column>
    <column>
        <originalName>Dátum posledného školenia OPP</originalName>
        <name>DatumPoslednehoSkoleniaOPP1</name>
        <visible>0</visible>
    </column>
</columns>
```

My code to iterate over all columns:

```
$schema = new DOMDocument();
$schema->load(BASE_PATH.'/schema.xml');
foreach ($schema->getElementsByTagName('column') as $column) {
    foreach($column->childNodes as $child) {
        echo $child->nodeName, ' => ', $child->nodeValue, '<br />';
    }
}
```

Now the output is most odd. I don't understand why the '#text =>' keeps appearing there:

```
#text =>
originalName => ORP
#text =>
name => ORP
#text =>
visible => 1
#text =>
#text =>
originalName => OKRES
#text =>
name => OKRES
#text =>
visible => 1
#text =>
#text =>
originalName => Objekt
#text =>
name => Objekt
#text =>
visible => 1
#text =>
#text =>
originalName => Školenie
#text =>
name => Skolenie
#text =>
visible => 1
#text =>
#text =>
originalName => Dátum posledného školenia OPP
#text =>
name => DatumPoslednehoSkoleniaOPP
#text =>
visible => 1
#text =>
#text =>
originalName => Dátum posledného školenia OPP
#text =>
name => DatumPoslednehoSkoleniaOPP1
#text =>
visible => 0
#text =>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could skip the DOMText elements:

```
$schema = new DOMDocument();
$schema->load(BASE_PATH.'/schema.xml');
foreach ($schema->getElementsByTagName('column') as $column) {
    foreach($column->childNodes as $child) {
        if ($child instanceof DOMElement) { // (! $child instanceof DOMText)
            echo $child->nodeName, ' => ', $child->nodeValue, '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Or use DOMXPath:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load(BASE_PATH.'/schema.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach($xpath->query('/columns/column/*') as $child)
{
    echo $child->nodeName, ' => ', $child->nodeValue, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try and `load()` with the [`LIBXML_NOBLANKS`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) option?

Alternatively `loadXML()` might do what you want (I'm guessing here).

---

According to [*PHP, DOM and XML : Part 2 – DOMDocument*](http://w3mentor.com/learn/php-mysql-tutorials/php-xml/php-dom-and-xml-part-2-domdocument/) you should either:

```
$schema->load(BASE_PATH.'/schema.xml', LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
```

Or

```
$schema = new DOMDocument();
$schema->preserveWhiteSpace = false; // This is the important part
$schema->load(BASE_PATH.'/schema.xml');
```

Depending on your PHP version.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$schema = new DOMDocument();
$schema->load('schema.xml');
foreach ($schema->getElementsByTagName('column') as $column) {
    $array = false;$i=0;
    foreach ($column->childNodes as $childNode){
        $array[$i] = $childNode->firstChild->nodeValue;
        $i++;
    }
    echo $array[1]." = > ".$array[3]." = > ".$array[5]."<br>";
}
?>
```

try this one... its not by falowing standards and bla bla bla or something like that but it works! :P

p.s. [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xmlphp1.html) you have some explanations/tutorials if you want read...

Comment: Take a look at my schema, there is no '#text' element there whatsoever. It should not get printed.

Comment: try with this print_r($child); and then you will se that there is #text :) (DOMText Object ( ) originalName => ORP), (DOMElement Object ( ) #text => )

Comment: use echo $child->nodeValue."<br>"; and you will get it clean... dont know for what you need it!